# How do I validate that a version number is valid using a regexp in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to validate that the version number is matching a version pattern but it seems that the check fails for some weird reason.

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION="1.2.3"
if [[ $VERSION =~ ^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$ ]]; then
 echo "INFO:<-->Version $VERSION"
else
 echo "ERROR:<->Unable to validate package version: '$VERSION'"
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Just replace `\d` with `[0-9]`. Do you really want to allow matching `*` string? You can also use `^([0-9]+\.){0,2}(\*|[0-9]+)$`, it is shorter

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why would you say that?  `\d` and `[0-9]` are exactly the same... http://uploads.im/9Bc8Y.png

Comment: @Shafizadeh I'm not sure that bash supports `\d`

Comment: @Thomas Oh .. So that's the point .. ok tnx

Comment: bash uses the posix char classes: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_03.html#sect_04_03_02

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in Bash instead of `\d` (as Bash does not support this shorthand character class), and I suggest shortening the pattern with the help of a [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) and putting the pattern into a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION="1.2.3"
rx='^([0-9]+\.){0,2}(\*|[0-9]+)$'
if [[ $VERSION =~ $rx ]]; then
 echo "INFO:<-->Version $VERSION"
else
 echo "ERROR:<->Unable to validate package version: '$VERSION'"
 exit 1
fi
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/HaBgpA)

The `([0-9]+\.){0,2}` parts matches 1 or more digits followed with a literal dot 0, 1, or 2 times.

Comment: Here is a little modification to the regex, if you also want to match suffixes like `1.2.3-dev` (which are "allowed" by semver) `rx='^([0-9]+\.){2,2}(\*|[0-9]+)(\-.*){0,1}$'`

Comment: @MichaelLihs Or, a bit cleaner version of the same pattern, `rx='^([0-9]+\.){2}(\*|[0-9]+)(-.*)?$'`