# Bash Regex to check if first character of string is a number

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm writing a script that uses trace route. I'm iterating through each line of the trace route and then through each word (separated by whitespace). However, sometimes the trace route returns a `*` character, which causes issues when echoing (filenames are output).

I've been fiddling with RegEx and so far I've come up with this:

```
if [[ $item =~ ^\d ]];
```

Item is a portion of the trace route.

For each item in a trace route line, I would simply like to check if the first character is equal to a number or not, then continue accordingly.

Comment: You need to use `if [[ $item =~ ^[0-9] ]];`, `\d` is not supported.

Comment: `^[[:digit:]]` will also work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894043/how-do-i-validate-that-a-version-number-is-valid-using-a-regexp-in-bash/35894180#35894180

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\d` is not supported in [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (used by Bash). You need to replace it with `[0-9]` like so:

```
if [[ $item =~ ^[0-9] ]];
```

Check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17968116/5620297)

Could also use `[:digit:]` to make it easier to read:

```
if [[ $item =~ ^[[:digit:]] ]];
```

Comment: That should be `^[[:digit:]]` - `[:digit:]` is a character class that needs to go inside a bracket expression.

Comment: @TomFenech Sorry, that was me typing quickly! Corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regex just glob is sufficient:

```
[[ $item == [0-9]* ]] && echo "it starts with a digit"
```

You can also use:

```
[[ $item == [[:digit:]]* ]]
```

Comment: BTW, do you know what is more efficient in Bash: globs or regexes?

Comment: In general regex are considered slower than glob patterns but I haven't done any serious benchmarking myself.